# Extract specific columns and others columns containing certain characters in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose for a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-1-1", "2021-1-2", "2021-1-3", "2021-1-4", 
"2021-1-5", "2021-1-6"), buy_price_actual = 1:6, call_price_actual = 2:7, 
    sell_price_actual = 3:8, buy_price_pred = 4:9, call_price_pred = 5:10, 
    sell_price_pred = 6:11), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Out:

```
       date buy_price_actual call_price_actual sell_price_actual buy_price_actual.1 call_price_pred sell_price_pred
1 2021-1-1 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 2021-1-2 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 2021-1-3 3 4 5 6 7 8
4 2021-1-4 4 5 6 7 8 9
5 2021-1-5 5 6 7 8 9 10
6 2021-1-6 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

I want to extract `date` column and the actual and predicted values of *buy* and *sell* prices in a for loop:

```
cols <- list(
   c("date", "buy_price_actual", "buy_price_pred"),
   c("date", "sell_price_actual", "sell_price_pred")
   )

for (col in cols){
   print(col)
}

for (col in cols){
   df1 <- df %>%
     select(col)
   print(df1)
}
```

Out:

```
      date buy_price_actual buy_price_pred
1 2021-1-1                1              4
2 2021-1-2                2              5
3 2021-1-3                3              6
4 2021-1-4                4              7
5 2021-1-5                5              8
6 2021-1-6                6              9
      date sell_price_actual sell_price_pred
1 2021-1-1                 3               6
2 2021-1-2                 4               7
3 2021-1-3                 5               8
4 2021-1-4                 6               9
5 2021-1-5                 7              10
6 2021-1-6                 8              11
```

Another way to deal with it is to search for keywords through `grep`, and add `date` column:

```
price_types <- c('buy', 'sell')
for (price_type in price_types){
   df1 <- df %>%
     select_if(grepl('date'|price_type, names(.)))
   print(df1)
}
```

However, there are still bugs in the above two solutions, how to deal with them? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if just typos, but there's a `"buy_price_pred"` in `cols` that does not exist in df and there's a pipe before `print(df1)` call, fixing the column name and either removing the pipe or changing the print to `%>% print()`  will fix the first loop. In 2nd loop the first parameter of grepl should be a valid string, `grepl(paste0('date|',price_type), ... )`. Though you might want to check something like `lapply(cols, \(x) select(df, x))` and `lapply(price_types, \(x) select(df, date, contains(x)))` to replace those loops

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I edited the typos in `df`, your first solution works. For the solution with `grepl` and `lapply`, do you mind post your code as the answers of this question? Since `df %>% select_if(grepl(paste0('date|', price_type), ... ))` returns an error: `Error in is_logical(.predicate) : '...' used in an incorrect context`. Furthermore, I think maybe we should use `enquo` to solve this issue? https://rpubs.com/lionel-/tidyeval-introduction

Comment: The error you added is somewhat misleading as this is what you get when you already have `df1`  object in your environment. With a clean env you should get `Error in as.pairlist(list(...)) : object 'df1' not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop fails because there's an extra pipe, the last one in `df1 <- df %>% select(col) %>% print(df1)`, so the expression evaluates as `df1 <- print(select(df, col), df1)` which you probably don't want.
Try this instead:

```r
for (col in cols){
  df1 <- df %>%
    select(col)
  print(df1)
}
```

In the 2nd loop you still have to construct a valid string to use as a first parameter of `grepl()`, for example with `paste0()` :

```r
price_types <- c('buy', 'sell')
for (price_type in price_types){
  df1 <- df %>%
    select_if(grepl(paste0('date|',price_type), names(.)))
  print(df1)
}
```

Though I'd rather use something like this instead:

```r
library(dplyr)

# add names
cols <- list(
  "buy"  = c("date", "buy_price_actual", "buy_price_pred"),
  "sell" = c("date", "sell_price_actual", "sell_price_pred")
)
lapply(cols, \(x) select(df, all_of(x)))
#> $buy
#>       date buy_price_actual buy_price_pred
#> 1 2021-1-1                1              4
#> 2 2021-1-2                2              5
#> 3 2021-1-3                3              6
#> 4 2021-1-4                4              7
#> 5 2021-1-5                5              8
#> 6 2021-1-6                6              9
#> 
#> $sell
#>       date sell_price_actual sell_price_pred
#> 1 2021-1-1                 3               6
#> 2 2021-1-2                 4               7
#> 3 2021-1-3                 5               8
#> 4 2021-1-4                 6               9
#> 5 2021-1-5                 7              10
#> 6 2021-1-6                 8              11
```

```r
price_types <- c('buy', 'sell')
lapply(setNames(price_types, price_types), \(x) select(df, date, contains(x)))
#> $buy
#>       date buy_price_actual buy_price_pred
#> 1 2021-1-1                1              4
#> 2 2021-1-2                2              5
#> 3 2021-1-3                3              6
#> 4 2021-1-4                4              7
#> 5 2021-1-5                5              8
#> 6 2021-1-6                6              9
#> 
#> $sell
#>       date sell_price_actual sell_price_pred
#> 1 2021-1-1                 3               6
#> 2 2021-1-2                 4               7
#> 3 2021-1-3                 5               8
#> 4 2021-1-4                 6               9
#> 5 2021-1-5                 7              10
#> 6 2021-1-6                 8              11
```

Input:

```r
df <- structure(list(
  date = c(
    "2021-1-1", "2021-1-2", "2021-1-3", "2021-1-4","2021-1-5", "2021-1-6"
  ), buy_price_actual = 1:6, call_price_actual = 2:7, sell_price_actual = 3:8, 
  buy_price_pred = 4:9, call_price_pred = 5:10,sell_price_pred = 6:11
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -6L
))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed solutions and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate two dataframes names df_buy and df_sell by looping over the two strings and selecting the columns containing that string as well as 'date'. We use `assign()` to name the dataframe according to the string as well:

```
library(dplyr)

for (string in c('buy','sell')) {
  assign(paste0("df_",string), df %>%
           select(matches(paste0("date|",string))))
}
```

Comment: Nope, I try to get an alternative conciser result same as this code generates `cols <- list(
  c("date", "buy_price_actual", "buy_price_pred"), 
  c("date", "call_price_actual", "call_price_pred")
  )
for (col in cols){
  print(col)
}

for (col in cols){
  df1 <- df %>%
    select(col) 
  print(df1)
}`

Comment: so two separate dataframes, one for buy and one for sell?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will generate two seperate plots for each of them.

Comment: I updated the answer to generate two dataframes (or as many as you want by editing the vector of strings)

Comment: I edit your code to `for (string in c('buy','sell')) {
  assign(paste0("df_", string), df %>%
           select(matches(paste0("date|", string))) %>% 
           print()
         )
}`, it returns the expected result, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with `map` functions

```r
vars <- c('buy','call','sell')
map(vars, ~ df %>% select(date, starts_with(.x)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
[[1]]
      date buy_price_actual buy_price_pred
1 2021-1-1                1              4
2 2021-1-2                2              5
3 2021-1-3                3              6
4 2021-1-4                4              7
5 2021-1-5                5              8
6 2021-1-6                6              9

[[2]]
      date call_price_actual call_price_pred
1 2021-1-1                 2               5
2 2021-1-2                 3               6
3 2021-1-3                 4               7
4 2021-1-4                 5               8
5 2021-1-5                 6               9
6 2021-1-6                 7              10

[[3]]
      date sell_price_actual sell_price_pred
1 2021-1-1                 3               6
2 2021-1-2                 4               7
3 2021-1-3                 5               8
4 2021-1-4                 6               9
5 2021-1-5                 7              10
6 2021-1-6                 8              11
```